# selected checkbox even after reload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need checkbox selected after page reload I am trying this code.
Here my check box

```
<tr>
  <td class="label" style="text-align:right">Company:</td>
  <td class="bodyBlack">
    <%=c B.getCompanyName() %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="bodyBlack" id="check" name="all" value='all' onClick="checkBox12()" style="margin-left:-691px">> Show all paid and unpaid transactions
    <br>
  </td>
</tr>
//here java script code
<script type="text/javascript">
  function checkBox12() {
    var jagdi = document.getElementById("check").value;
    if (jagdi != "") {
      document.getElementById("check").checked = true;
    }
    console.log("jagdi is " + jagdi);
    //here my url
    window.location.replace("/reports/buyers/statementAccount.jsp?all=" + jagdi);
    return $('#check').is(':checked');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use only jQuery ?

```
function checkBox12()
{
  var jagdi = false;
  if($("#check").length != 0) // use this if you wanted to verify if the element #check is present
    jagdi = $("#check").prop("checked");

 //here my url
 window.location.replace("/reports/buyers/statementAccount.jsp?all="+jagdi);
}
```

For answer your question, you can check your checkbox when the document is ready

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $("check").prop("checked", true");
   });`

But the better way is to add `checked="checked"` in your HTML. The checkbox will be checked by default. /!\ input need "/" in close tag

```
<input type="checkbox" class="bodyBlack" id="check" name="all"  value='all' onClick="checkBox12()"  style="margin-left:-691px" checked="checked" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute checked=checked in your html input tag:

```
<input checked="checked" type="checkbox" class="bodyBlack" id="check" name="all"  value='all' onClick="checkBox12()"  style="margin-left:-691px"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using some other base language. I use php , and it overs POST, GET and SESSION to store values globally and for time you need.

Better find a equivalent function in your language. worth it in long term and on project expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You can store state of checkbox on cookie and repopulate it after page reload.

also there is an example in here [HERE!](http://hibbard.eu/how-to-persist-checkbox-checked-state-after-page-reload/)

```
  $(":checkbox").on("change", function(){
    var checkboxValues = {};
    $(":checkbox").each(function(){
      checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
    });
    $.cookie('checkboxValues', checkboxValues, { expires: 7, path: '/' })
  });

  function repopulateCheckboxes(){
    var checkboxValues = $.cookie('checkboxValues');
    if(checkboxValues){
      Object.keys(checkboxValues).forEach(function(element) {
        var checked = checkboxValues[element];
        $("#" + element).prop('checked', checked);
      });
    }
  }

  $.cookie.json = true;
  repopulateCheckboxes();
```